# Rename tag [qtchart]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The tag refers to Qt Charts, and is used accordingly; it seems to be a typo.

Please rename: [qtchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtchart) -> [qtcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qtcharts)